# Stop asyncio.run() from Ignoring the Remainder of My Code

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I intend to run a single asynchronous function (that does things relevant to other parts of the program, but returns nothing) for as long as my synchronous code continues running. Right after I run the `asyncio.run()` command, though, the program only performs the asynchronous command forever.

I've tried some elementary threading and multiprocressing Pool approaches, but I found this to be the most successful of what I've attempted:

```py
# There's some code up here (A), and it runs synchronously and fine.

# Here's the asynchronous code (B).
pauseAsynchronousFunction = False

async def asynchronousFunction():
    global pauseAsynchronousFunction
    # Do stuff before hitting the while loop.
    while True:
        if pauseAsynchronousFunction == False:
            # Do some stuff.
        else:
            # Do some other stuff.

asyncio.run(pauseAsynchronousFunction())

# More synchronous code is down here (C), which it never reaches.
```

I can tell that it's not working as I expect because another function below (in C) calls the same global variable `pauseAsynchronousFunction` and toggles it from `False` to `True`, and then back to `False` again once it finishes running. That toggle never occurs.

I'm guessing that the problem has either to do with the `while True`, which I'm not understanding why if it's asynchronous, or that it's got something to do with not containing an `await` statement. What else might I be missing?

**UPDATE:**

I worked through a few debug attempts with some help from pypypy, and got this.

```py
pauseAsynchronousFunction = False

async def fun2():
    global pauseAsynchronousFunction
    while True:
        if pauseAsynchronousFunction == False:
            #do stuff
        else:
            #do other stuff

async def fun1():
    global pauseAsynchronousFunction
    pauseAsynchronousFunction = True
    #do stuff here that you wanted to do after the `asyncio.run` above
    pauseAsynchronousFunction = False
    return stuff

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        fun1(),
        fun2(),
    )

asyncio.run(main)
```

The problem appears to be this: 
`pauseAsynchronousFunction` toggles to `True`, but it doesn't toggle back to `False` at the end of `fun(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asyncio.run` will block until your asynchronous functions have all returned. So the code you have after the `asyncio.run()` should be converted to an async function i.e.

```
import asyncio

async def fun2():
    global pauseAsynchronousFunction
    while True:
        if pauseAsynchronousFunction == False:
            print('not paused')
        else:
            print('paused')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def fun1():
    global pauseAsynchronousFunction
    pauseAsynchronousFunction = True
    print('im pausing')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('im unpausing')
    pauseAsynchronousFunction = False
    return 0

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        fun1(),
        fun2(),
    )

await main()
```

Here is an alternative answer using threading and Events:

```
import threading
import time

should_pause = threading.Event()

def fun2():
    while True:
        if should_pause.is_set():
            print('paused')
        else:
            print('not paused')
        time.sleep(1)


t = threading.Thread(target=fun2)
t.start()
should_pause.set()
print('waiting')
time.sleep(5)
print('finished-waiting')
should_pause.clear()
```

Comment: I think I get this, but just want to be clear on a few things: (1) Once I go async at asyncio.run(), and I want one of the asyncs to run (effectively) forever, there's no going back to sync. Is this right? (2) I can just shove all of my (C) code into fun1().

Comment: That’s correct. If you really need an long running code block and the rest of your code is synchronous consider running it in another thread.

Comment: I tried a few variations of this. The fun1() isn't toggling the `pauseAsynchronousFunction` value. It looks like it's just running the two functions synchronously.

Comment: I've updated the example to use gather() which should simultaneously execute the functions.

Comment: Oddly, that stopped task1 from working. Let me edit your code just for a second so that a potential problem becomes clearer.

Comment: The `await asyncio.gather(fun(1), fun(2),)` had the same effect as the building of Tasks did.

Comment: Yes that’s correct. Gather is just a less verbose way of writing multiple tasks.  Could you update your question with the new issue you are having, I don’t understand what the problem is.

Comment: I've updated the question and, looking through my code, at least identified the problem. It doesn't make sense that `pauseAsynchronousFunction` won't toggle back to `False`. Or, maybe that fun(2) doesn't catch when it re-evaluates?

Comment: I have updated the answer with two working solutions - it seems that if the first task `fun2()` never awaits anything then it will maintain control and continue running indefinitely. I think the thread solution is the better choice here without understanding the exact use case.

Comment: The thread solution was better, more elegant. I fundamentally misunderstood `Event` objects in the documentation and applied them incorrectly before moving to asyncio. Thanks!